# Is/was there a word that pairs with "while" the same way "then" pairs with "if"?

Tags: single-word-requests, archaicisms

*If* you understand these examples`,` you'll notice that I’m wondering whether both of these commas could be considered to be standing in for words.

*While* I’m not sure such a word ever existed`,` I’ll even accept ones no longer in common use.

*If* you happen to know such a word *then* please post an answer.

Comment: No. The conjunction `while` cannot be used to form conditionals. It can only be used to express contrast ("while I like cheese, she doesn't"), or simultaneity ("while she dreams, he snores"). Your second sentence is an example of the latter.

Comment: @ekhumoro I don’t read the question as asking for a pairing that applies solely to conditionals alone, but rather to any possible pairing, like the way *not only...but also* pairs together without in any way being a conditional.

Comment: While there just may be such a single word, the probability is that there isn't.

Comment: @tchrist. In that case, how to interpret the explicit reference to commas? Also, the question is asking for a word that functions "in the same way" that "then" pairs with "if". That all seems pretty specific - maybe some clarification is needed?

Comment: _While_ can be used to form conditionals. One example is "Make hay while the sun shines", or if you prefer "While the sun shines, make hay." As a programmer, I'm tempted to [pair _while_ with _do_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop); while X is the case, do Y. Another possibility is to pair with _continue to (do)_.

Comment: @SteveLovell Linguists do not normally consider the clause governed by *while* to be the protasis of a conditional.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist, I wouldn't know what linguists normally think. I just know that as a philosopher and programmer, the logic seems equivalent to me. It's the logic I have in mind when I refer to these statements as _conditional_.

Comment: @SteveLovell. That's just another example of simultaneity. Sunshine and haymaking often happen at the same time, but they aren't conditional upon each other. Also: `programming_language != human_language`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I've always understood that phrase as meaning you should do it while you can since when it starts to rain you won't be able to do it any longer. To my mind that is the very definition of _conditional_.

Comment: @SteveLovell. Grammatically, the `while` is there to indicate that two things are happening at the same time. Compare: "If the sun shines, make hay" (i.e. one thing following from another).

Comment: @ekhumoro, this isn't meant to be a discussion forum, so I'm going to stop. Other readers can make up their own minds.